# making a part of image transparent

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

How can you make a part of an image transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the image in a suitable image manipulation program, such as gimp. Clear out the parts you want to be transparent, and save it in a format that handles transparency, such as png or gif.

Comment: i want to put a small image behind a big image. big Image will have a rectangular area which is transparent and where the small image will appear. will it be possible in blackberry